# Error 524 de timeout en Webservice en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, wcf

Estoy utilizando una llamada de *Web Service* que lee correos, al leer 240 correos funciona perfecto, pero cuando es más de los 240 correos, me sale el siguiente error:

> El servidor remoto devolvió una respuesta inesperada: (524) Origin Time-out.

En el web.config del cliente está definido así:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://webservice.prueba.cl/ServicioWeb.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoap"
            contract="ServicioWebClienteLeeCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoap"
            name="ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

En el web.config del *Web Service* es:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>

           <binding name="ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoap" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
      openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Desde el cliente lo llamo así:

```
string stringconeccion = "bla bla bla";
ServicioWebClienteLeeCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoapClient servicio = new ServicioWebClienteLeeCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaCorreoSoapClient();
lbMensaje.Text = "Buscando ...";
var source = new BindingSource();
var list = servicio.Obtieneadjunto(txtHostCorreo.Text, txtUsuario.Text, txtPassword.Text, stringconeccion);
```

El error me da cuando uso el sitio de produccion del *Web Service*, pero cuando uso uno de mi computador (localhost), no hay problema.

Me gustaría saber como reparar el error, qué parámetro debería colocar o quizás aumentar algún rango del *timeout*. Le agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Saludos Danilo, por curiosidad, ¿Cuánto tiempo demora en leer esos 240 correos?

Comment: menos de 5 minutos

Comment: interesante, porque de acuerdo a lo leído en tu código, closeTimeout="00:30:00", openTimeout="00:30:00" , receiveTimeout="00:30:00", sendTimeout="00:30:00" todo apunta a media hora. ¿Cómo sabes que llegan a 240 correos? ¿Hay logs en el IIS?

Comment: porque lee correos no leídos, y le pongo la cantidad de no leídos

Comment: podemos hablar por el chat?

Comment: Igual lee todos los correos, pero me sale ese error. Resulta, que en el webservice a parte de leer, inserta los datos del correo en una transaccion, y como da el error deshace la transacción.

Comment: dale, vao al chat :D

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58214/discussion-between-danilo-and-fredyfx).